# Python Selenium run multiple test classes in one selenium webdriver using with pytest

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, pytest-html

I am new in python and I started to create an automation test suite about a GUI(multiple test cases in different file). I want to execute all my test cases in one selenium webdriver, so I created a singleton webdriver class and I want to use this class all my test cases. Here is my singleton webdriver class:

```
from selenium import webdriver


class Webdriver(object):
    """
    Singleton class based on overriding the __new__ method
    """

    def __new__(cls):
        """
        Override __new__ method to control the obj. creation
        :return: Singleton obj.
        """
        if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
            cls.instance = super(Webdriver, cls).__new__(cls)

        return cls.instance

    @staticmethod
    def get_driver():
        """
        :return: Selenium driver
        """
        dir = "C:\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\ie"
        ie_driver_path = dir + "\\IEDriverServer.exe"
        return webdriver.Ie(ie_driver_path)
```

and my setUp example:

```
from Core.Webdriver import Webdriver

class LoginExternal(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # Create Instances
        self.web = Webdriver.get_driver()
        self.matcher = TemplateMatcher()
        self.gif = GifCapture("C:\\wifi\\Videos\\" + self._testMethodName + ".gif")
        self.gif.start()
        time.sleep(3)

     def test_LoginExternal(self):
         # Open External Login Page
         self.web.maximize_window()
```

Here is my problem, when I execute my test suite, my code create a new selenium instance but I want only one selenium instance to be used in all test cases.

I use pytest as a test runner with following cmd command:

```
pytest --pyargs --html=Report/External_04052018.html ExternalTestSuite/
```

I think the problem is pytest use a new proccess in every test case execution. Is there any way to prevent or use like this way?

Comment: If you are using `pytest`, why don't you use fixture for selenium web driver creation?

Comment: I do not know how to use pytest fixture in this case. Could you give me a little example for my case?

Comment: last night I searched pytest fixture and found this: "Fixtures aren't supported in unittest.TestCase subclasses - if you want to use pytest features, use classes without any inheritance (or inheriting object on Python 2).", so I think pytest fixture is not my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pytest greatest feature and advantage over traditional XUnit family test runners is that it has fixtures. I invite you to use it. In your scenario, I would get rid of extending `unittest.TestCase` and `setUp` method in favor of pytest fixture as follows:

```
import pytest

from Core.Webdriver import Webdriver


class TestLoginExternal:

    @pytest.fixture(scope='class')
    def driver(self):
        print('Setup runs once before all tests in class')
        driver = Webdriver.get_driver()
        yield driver
        driver.quit()
        print('Teardown runs once after all tests in class')

    def test_LoginExternal(self, driver):
        # Open External Login Page
        print('test_LoginExternal')

    def test_LoginInternal(self, driver):
        # Open External Login Page
        print('test_LoginInternal')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try it on monday but I have a little question. Every test cases that I create are a different python file, I did not write all my test cases in one file. The structure which is in your example is successful in my test suite?

Comment: If you have multiple files with tests and you want to use one and only driver instance in all test cases you will need to define `driver` fixture in `conftest.py` file - https://docs.pytest.org/en/3.5.0/fixture.html?highlight=conftest#conftest-py-sharing-fixture-functions